# Need help in Linq Queries left Outer Join

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, outer-join

how can i write this in LINQ :

```
SELECT 
    T.TestId,
    S.SubjectName+' >> '+T.TestName +' ('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),COUNT(Q.TestId)) +')' TestData
FROM 
    Test T LEFT OUTER JOIN Subject S
    ON T.SubjectId = S.SubjectId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Quest Q
    ON T.TestId = Q.TestId
GROUP BY 
    Q.TestId, 
    T.TestId,
    T.TestName,
    S.SubjectName
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(Q.TestId) DESC
```

Need help in writing Left Outer Join & Group by  in LINQ .

Case II :

```
SELECT 
    S.SubjectName,
    T.TestName,
    Q.Question,
    A.Answer,
    A.IsCorrect
FROM Ans A
    INNER JOIN Quest Q
    ON A.QuestId = Q.QuestId
    AND A.QuestId IN ( SELECT 
                            Q.QuestId
                        FROM Quest Q
                            INNER JOIN Test T
                            ON Q.TestId = T.TestId )
    INNER JOIN Subject S
    ON A.SubjectId = S.SubjectId
    INNER JOIN Test T
    ON A.TestId = T.TestId
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform an outer join in Linq, you need to use the `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method:

```
var query =
    from t in db.Test
    join s in db.Subject on t.SubjectId equals s.SubjectId into testSubject
    from s in testSubject.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join q in db.Quest on t.TestId equals q.TestId into testQuest
    from q in testQuest.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group by new
    {
        t.TestId,
        t.TestName,
        s.SubjectName
    }
    select new
    {
        g.Key.TestId,
        g.Key.TestName,
        g.Key.SubjectName,
        Count = g.Count()
    };

var results = from r in query.AsEnumerable()
              select new
              {
                  r.TestId,
                  TestData = string.Format("{0} >> {1} ({2})", r.SubjectName, t.TestName, r.Count);
              }
```

Note that you don't need both `t.TestId` and `q.TestId` in the `group by` clause, since they will have the same value. For the last part, I'm using `AsEnumerable` so that the final projection is performed in memory rather than in the DB, which enables the use of `string.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mappings, it should be easy without any joins:

```
from test in tests
let count = test.Quests.Count()
orderby count descending
select
    new
    {
        test.Id,
        TestData =
            test.Subject == null
                ? null
                : string.Format("{0} >> {1} ({2})", test.Subject.Name, test.Name, count)
    };
```

**EDIT:** After reading Thomas Levesque's answer, I realized this wouldn't work, but the following should:

```
var query = from test in tests
            let count = test.Quests.Count()
            orderby count descending
            select
                new
                {
                    test.Id,
                    test.Name,
                    test.Subject,
                    Count = count
                };

var results = query
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(
        t =>
        new
        {
            t.Id,
            TestData =
            t.Subject == null
                ? null
                : string.Format("{0} >> {1} ({2})", t.Subject.Name, t.Name, t.Count)
        });

        results.Dump();
    }
```